# View which turns into a header view on Scroll (Gmail and Google +)

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I would like to recreate this behaviour in my app. Gmail and Google + have it in common.

Its a view that turns into a header view when scrolling through the body of information.

It is not a fixed view as seen in the image on the left, it becomes fixed after the user has started scrolling through.

Has anyone done this before or could anyone recommend a way of doing this.

Thanks

Here's an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define your header as layout in separate xml file.

Like: header.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <LinearLayout>
    <!-- Contains all views as shown above in the image(ie Image of G,TextViews, Start Image,  
         BackImage, Menu Image) -->
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Now, You can include this header where ever you want in your xml as header.
Using:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header" />
```

Example: `main_activity.xml`

```
<LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout>
            <!-- Contains your remaining item or view of layout -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope that what you are looking for....

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your answer above is assuming that there is nothing above the hanging header view. If you see the images above. You'll notice that there is actually some other information above that view (which turns into a header later. As you scroll through the first view, that part of the content turns into a header.